# React Link to and If Statement

Tags: reactjs, onclick, local-storage, link-to

so I have a function that I want to link to different pages of my project when a button is clicked.
Function below:

```
displayCharacterProfile() {
let getCharacterName = localStorage.getItem("characterName");

if(getCharacterName == "littlefinger") {
<Link to="/littlefinger"></Link>
}

if(getCharacterName == "tywin") {
<Link to="/tywin"></Link>
}
}


render() {
return (
<button className="enter" onClick={this.displayCharacterProfile}> Enter </button>
);
}
```

Any quick help would be greatly appreciated guys! Thank you :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to StackOverflow! When you render a `Link` element, all it does is display a link to the user. The user has to actually *click* it in order to go there. Try this:

```
render() {
  let getCharacterName = localStorage.getItem("characterName");
  return (
    <button className="enter">
      <Link to={"/" + getCharacterName}> Enter </Link>
    </button>
  );
}
```

Comment: It would probably be better to pass the character name in as a prop and have some other component handle the `localStorage` call, but I guess that's not technically related to your question :)

Comment: Thanks a bunch for your quick and accurate response!! It's now working :-)

Comment: Awesome! Glad it’s working. Don’t forget to accept and upvote an answer if it was helpful!